# Why do position operators in orthogonal directions commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, non-commutative-theory

In three dimensions, we have $\hat x$, $\hat y$, $\hat z$ as the position operators in the three orthogonal directions. If the components of angular momentum don't commute, why must these all commute? I can't seem to find an answer elsewhere. For example, [this](http://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/P342.S10/Physics342/page1/files/Lecture.21.pdf) states that the *"coordinate operators clearly commute"* without explanation. Is this an experimental fact or a postulate or something else?

Comment: It's a postulate.

Comment: Also I really don't recommend using any resource that feels the need to say "obviously" and "clearly" 4 times in one page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an assumption that seems to be born out by the experimental evidence thus far.

Non-commutative quantum mechanics is a speculative theory that introduces a degree of non-commutativity between the components of the position operator. This introduces a sort of minimum length scale into the theory, beyond which it is not possible to localize a particle. This is a generic prediction of a certain perspective on quantum theories of gravity. In these theories it is expected that probing particles at high enough energies will lead to the postulated non-commutativity.

Answer (score 0):

In position representation these operators are simply equivalent to multiplying the wave function by the corresponding variable, so it is easy to see that they commute. For example,
$$
\langle \hat{x}\rangle=\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*\hat{x}\psi(x,y,z)=
\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*x\psi(x,y,z)=\int dxdy dz x\left|\psi(x,y,z)\right|^2,\\
\langle \hat{y}\rangle=\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*\hat{y}\psi(x,y,z)
=\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*y\psi(x,y,z)=\int dxdy dz y\left|\psi(x,y,z)\right|^2
$$
Thus
$$\langle \hat{x}\hat{y}\rangle=\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*\hat{x}\hat{y}\psi(x,y,z)
=\int dxdy dz \psi(x,y,z)^*xy\psi(x,y,z)=\\\int dxdy dz xy\left|\psi(x,y,z)\right|^2=
\langle \hat{y}\hat{x}\rangle
$$
Same can be shown for the momentum operators (which are derivatives in the position representation.)

> If the components of angular momentum don't commute, why must these all commute?

It is easy to see that, if $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$ commute and $\hat{p}_x,\hat{p}_y,\hat{p}_z$ commute, then the angular momentum operators do not commute just because $\hat{x}$ does not commute with $\hat{p}_x$ (and same for $y,z$). Indeed, angular momentum operators are obtained by definition as
$$
\hat{\mathbf{L}}=\hat{x}\times\hat{p}\rightarrow
\hat{L}_x=\hat{y}\hat{p}_z-\hat{z}\hat{p}_y,
\hat{L}_y=\hat{z}\hat{p}_x-\hat{x}\hat{p}_z,
\hat{L}_z=\hat{x}\hat{p}_y-\hat{y}\hat{p}_x
$$
I leave calculating their commutation as a homework exercise (or lookup in the QM book.)

Comment: If the commutation relation between $x$ and $y$ are unknown, you're not allowed to identify $\psi(x,y)$ with the state, since this assumes the basis set for $x$ AND $y$ exists. You cannot do this if $x$ and $y$ do not commute.

Comment: @ChangHexiang Your comment is not very clear - you seem to be using the quantities and their operators interchangebly.

Answer (score -1):

$\hat{x}$ operator takes a quantum state and multiplies by a number $x$ and $\hat{y}$ operator takes a quantum state multiplies by a number $y$. So since $x$ and $y$ are now numbers after the operators hit the quantum states, then $[\hat{x},\hat{y}] = [\hat{y},\hat{x}]$.